# Regression output double and with capital letter

Tags: r, regression

I am doing a linear regression in R. The output shows some variables (`equity` & `Equity`, and `loan` & `Loan`) double and one is written with a capital letter. In the dataset, they are always written in lowercase but appear in two different ways when I run the regression. I do not find the answer online, so maybe some of you can help me out? Any ideas are highly appreciated!

```
Model1 <- lm(Lifetime_CO2 ~ signatory + as.factor(Finance_Type), data = Data_dup)
summary(Model1)

Coefficients:
                                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                 90.351      4.397  20.550  < 2e-16 ***
signatory                                    7.378      1.732   4.259 2.10e-05 ***
as.factor(Finance_Type)equity              -29.059      4.640  -6.263 4.18e-10 ***
as.factor(Finance_Type)Equity               14.549     38.971   0.373 0.708914    
as.factor(Finance_Type)government grant    -81.284     22.784  -3.568 0.000365 ***
as.factor(Finance_Type)insurance            -2.810     16.397  -0.171 0.863948    
as.factor(Finance_Type)loan                -25.183      4.422  -5.695 1.32e-08 ***
as.factor(Finance_Type)Loan                 14.549     27.731   0.525 0.599852    
as.factor(Finance_Type)refinancing bond     -9.728     19.878  -0.489 0.624578    
as.factor(Finance_Type)refinancing equity  -40.601     27.731  -1.464 0.143252    
as.factor(Finance_Type)refinancing loan    -26.889      5.344  -5.031 5.09e-07 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert upper-case characters in the `Finance_Type` column to lower-case, or vice versa.

By the way, `as.factor()` is not needed unless you want to re-order levels of a categorical variable.

```r
Data_dup$Finance_Type <- tolower(Data_dup$Finance_Type)

Model1 <- lm(Lifetime_CO2 ~ signatory + Finance_Type, data = Data_dup)
summary(Model1)
```

Comment: I wasn't clear enough in my question - there is only "equity" in the Finance_Type column. The capital letters only appear when I run the regression.

Comment: So sorry, I checked again and your solution worked - seems like I just didn't see the different spelling versions  - thanks a lot!

Comment: @Lilly Glad to help you. You would have discovered it if you ran `table(Data_dup$Finance_Type)` or `unique(Data_dup$Finance_Type)` that are able to show the unique elements in a vector.

Comment: create! Thanks! I will use this next time :)